# jQuery Validate - "Either skip these fields, or fill at least X of them"

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) on my forms. I have some groups of fields that are optional, but need to be either "all or nothing" - if you fill one input in a group, you must fill all of them.

For example, imagine the user can input one location - street, city, state, and zip - or multiple locations. You don't have to enter a second location, but if you do, it's not OK to just give the city; I need the state and zip for that one too.

To solve this problem, I wrote a custom rule - really just a tiny tweak of [my previous rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300994/jquery-validate-require-at-least-one-field-in-a-group-to-be-filled), `require_from_group`. This one is called `skip_or_fill_minimum`. Here's how you'd use it:

```
var validationrules = {
  rules: {
    location2address: {
    skip_or_fill_minimum: [4,'.location2']
  }
  //This input will validate if all 4 `.location2` inputs are filled,
  //or if all of them are left blank
}

var validator = $("#formtovalidate").validate(validationrules);
```

Here's the code for the custom rule:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("skip_or_fill_minimum", function(value, element, options) {
    var numberRequired = options[0];
    var selector = options[1];
    //Look for our selector within the parent form
    var numberFilled = $(selector, element.form).filter(function() {
         // Each field is kept if it has a value
         return $(this).val();
      }).length;
      var valid = numberFilled >= numberRequired || numberFilled === 0;

    //The elegent part - this element needs to check the others that match the
    //selector, but we don't want to set off a feedback loop where all the
    //elements check all the others which check all the others which
    //check all the others...
    //So instead we
    //  1) Flag all matching elements as 'currently being validated'
    //  using jQuery's .data()
    //  2) Re-run validation on each of them. Since the others are now
    //     flagged as being in the process, they will skip this section,
    //     and therefore won't turn around and validate everything else
    //  3) Once that's done, we remove the 'currently being validated' flag
    //     from all the elements
    if(!$(element).data('being_validated')) {
      var fields = $(selector, element.form);
      //.valid() means "validate using all applicable rules" (which includes this one)
      fields.data('being_validated', true);
      fields.validate(); //Changed from fields.valid();
      fields.data('being_validated', false);
    }
    return valid;
    // {0} below is the 0th item in the options field
    }, jQuery.format("Please either skip these fields or fill at least {0} of them."));
```

I'm primarily posting this so that others who search the web for a solution will find it. Still - **does anyone see a way to improve this?**

## Update - now part of jQuery Validation

This was [officially added to jQuery Validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/78a739f7c574c80547dfecd70b46a362efc8e8a7) on 4/3/2012.

Comment: Updated 4-9-2010 with the elegant part that re-checks other group members without causing an infinite loop. That logic is courtesy of Nick Craver - see this question about my related rule: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378472/jquery-validate-can-i-re-validate-a-group-of-fields-after-changing-one

Comment: Updated 8-22-2010 - changed .valid() to .validate() on fields.data; valid() was causing the whole form to pass validation when just these fields returned true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My shortened and "optimized" version (more chaining + use of validator custom provided selector). And hopefully makes less selection operations.

Still suffers from the same bugs your rule does -- what I mean is that the removing of the `error` class and the error labels on all elems which match our selector is not really correct. Just imagine you require 4 fields to be set but there are 5. User fills 4 fields. The fifth he leaves unfilled but on that field you additionally set `required` and `email`. This way the error-message for the email too gets removed although he didn't resolve it yet.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("skip_or_fill_minimum", function(value, element, options) {
    var elems = $(element).parents('form').find(options[1]);
    var numberFilled = elems.filter(':filled').size();
    if (numberFilled >= options[0] || numberFilled == 0) {
        elems.removeClass('error');
        elems.next('label.error').not('.checked').text('').addClass('checked');
        return true;
    } else {
        elems.addClass('error');
    }
}, jQuery.format("Please either skip these fields or fill at least {0} of them."));
```

Comment: Good suggestions. To some extent, my code was verbose on purpose in order to be a clear example, but I can learn a couple of things from your code. Thank you! Also - you're right about the incorrect behavior removing the errors. Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It took me quite a while to find the fix mentioned above for the problem where fields above the group would not get validated.

It would be good if the change of **.valid()** to **.validate()** was added to the closely related questions - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378472/jquery-validate-can-i-re-validate-a-group-of-fields-after-changing-one/2589646#2589646) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300994/jquery-validate-require-at-least-one-field-in-a-group-to-be-filled) as many people are asking about it.

This fix though stops all the groups labels from being shown or removed on key or blur events. I found [jitter's if else statement above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888976/jquery-validate-either-skip-these-fields-or-fill-at-least-x-of-them/1889879#1889879) to be very helpful in solving that.

**note:** stackoverflow has help me find many answers in the past, but this is my first actual contribution. Thanks all for bring together this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first post to SO, so I hope I'm doing this correctly, but there appears to be an error in the accepted solution. I have added the closing bracket for the `location2address` block (or the `rules` block, depending on how you look at it).

```
var validationrules = {
  rules: {
    location2address: {
      skip_or_fill_minimum: [4,'.location2']
    }
  }
  //This input will validate if all 4 `.location2` inputs are filled,
  //or if all of them are left blank
}
var validator = $("#groovetime_entry").validate(validationrules);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something slightly different.  It is a search form with Either or Both first or last name AND/OR 1 of 4 other search criteria.

I wanted them to either skip or ONLY enter one (or x).  I modified the code above:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("skip_or_fill_only_x", function (value, element, options) {
    var numberRequired = options[0];
    var selector = options[1];
    var numberFilled = $(selector, element.form).filter(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).length;
    //Changed this line from "numberFilled >=" to "numberFilled ==="
    var valid = numberFilled === numberRequired || numberFilled === 0;
    if (!$(element).data('being_validated')) {
        var fields = $(selector, element.form);
        fields.data('being_validated', true);
        fields.validate();
        fields.data('being_validated', false);
    }
    return valid;
//Adjusted message
}, jQuery.format("Please either skip these fields or only fill {0} of them."));
```

the full implementation looks like this:

```
    $('#advancedSearchForm').validate({
    errorLabelContainer: '#advancedErrors',
    rules: {
        FirstName: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
        },
        LastName: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
        },
        countryCodeAdvanced: {
            skip_or_fill_only_x: [1, '.location2']
        },
        location: {
            skip_or_fill_only_x: [1, '.location2']
        },
        PositionTitle: {
            skip_or_fill_only_x: [1, '.location2']
        },
        FunctionalArea: {
            skip_or_fill_only_x: [1, '.location2']
        }
    },
    groups: {
        mygroup: "FirstName LastName",
        location2: "countryCodeAdvanced location PositionTitle FunctionalArea"
    }
});


jQuery.validator.addMethod("skip_or_fill_only_x", function (value, element, options) {
    var numberRequired = options[0];
    var selector = options[1];
    var numberFilled = $(selector, element.form).filter(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).length;
    var valid = numberFilled === numberRequired || numberFilled === 0;
    if (!$(element).data('being_validated')) {
        var fields = $(selector, element.form);
        fields.data('being_validated', true);
        fields.validate();
        fields.data('being_validated', false);
    }
    return valid;
}, jQuery.format("Please either skip these fields or only fill {0} of them."));
```