# Validate(in terms blank field) any one out of two fields in jquery-1.9.1.min

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate(not allow blank) any field out of these two !Got some idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378472/jquery-validate-can-i-re-validate-a-group-of-fields-after-changing-one) but unable to implement it in 1.9.1 version.

Even both of the fields are validate,that's also fine.
Any inputs..... guys

Here is my jquery

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
    alert("xxx");
    var valid = $(options[1], element.form).filter(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).length >= options[0];

    if(!$(element).data('reval')) {
        var fields = $(options[1], element.form);
        fields.data('reval', true).valid();
        fields.data('reval', false);
    }
    return valid;
}, jQuery.format("'Please enter either username/ email address to recover password'/Please fill out at least {0} of these fields."));

$("#forgot_pass_form").validate({
    rules: {
        uname: { require_from_group: [1,".send_username"] },
        email: { require_from_group: [1,".send_password"] }
    }
});
```

​and here is my html

```
<form action="#" class="send_form" id="forgot_pass_form" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="send_row">
                        <label class="padding-top10">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="send_email" id="email" name="email" />
                        <em>You need to type an email address</em>
                    </div>

                    <div class="send_row option">OR</div>

                    <div class="send_row">
                        <label class="padding-top10">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="send_username" id="uname" name="uname" />
                    </div>


                    <div class="send_row send_submitforgotuser">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                </form>
```

I want just to validate any field out of these two blank fields.

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: the whole thing,even unable to see the alert :(

Comment: I copied it into JSFiddle and I got the alert

Comment: apart from alert, is rest of thing working ?

Comment: create demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate, out of two blank fields, at least one field must be filled or both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136943/jquery-validate-out-of-two-blank-fields-at-least-one-field-must-be-filled-or-b)

Answer (score 0):

Add a minlength property to each of the inputs. If you add minlength 1 they can't be blank. If you add the class "email" it will validate an email address.

HTML

```
<form action="#" class="send_form" id="forgot_pass_form" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="send_row">
            <label class="padding-top10">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="send_email email" id="email" name="email" />
            <em>You need to type an email address</em>
        </div>

        <div class="send_row option">OR</div>

        <div class="send_row">
            <label class="padding-top10">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="send_username" id="uname" name="uname" minlength="2" />
        </div>


        <div class="send_row send_submitforgotuser">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#forgot_pass_form").validate();
    $("#forgot_pass_form input").on('change', function() {
        if ($('#forgot_pass_form').valid()) {
            $('#forgot_pass_form input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#forgot_pass_form input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'true');
        }
    });
});
```

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/K2XAX/3/

Comment: Jeff thanks for this response,but want to validate blank any of the field before submit. but it's showing #403 & CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/K2XAX/2/

This is working fine. It validates before submitting. Just disable the submit button until one is filled out