# jQuery group Validation for multiple textboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to implement jQuery validation on homephone field. Currently my homephone field should contain 10 digit numbers. So I have 3 separate text boxes for that. First and Second text box accepts 3 numbers each whereas the last textbox accepts 4 numbers. Currently the validations are working fine. But what I want is a common message for all the three textboxes. Right now if I leave 1 text box the error message would display fine but as soon as I leave more than 1 text box the error message gets overlayed. Meaning the number of error message = number of textbox left. I want just one error message for any number of text boxes left while entering homephone number.The code is as follows

```
$("#signup").validate({
        rules: {
            "data[User][homephone1]": {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 3
            },
            "data[User][homephone2]": {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 3
            },
            "data[User][homephone3]": {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 4
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "data[User][homephone1]": {
                required: "Please enter a valid Phone Number",
                number: "",
                minlength: "",
                maxlength: ""
            },
            "data[User][homephone2]": {
                required: "Please enter a valid Phone Number",
                number: "",
                minlength: "",
                maxlength: ""
            },
            "data[User][homephone3]": {
                required: "Please enter a valid Phone Number",
                number: "",
                minlength: "",
                maxlength: ""
            }
```

There is a `group_from` attribute but I am not able to implement it.Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please post us the HTML.

Comment: On a side note, you could just use some [form helpers](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/phone/#jquery-plugins)

Comment: you might be looking for something like this



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136943/jquery-validate-out-of-two-blank-fields-at-least-one-field-must-be-filled-or-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"Currently the validations are working fine. But what I want is **a
> common message for all the three textboxes**. Right now if I leave 1
> text box the error message would display fine but as soon as I leave
> more than 1 text box the error message gets overlayed. Meaning the
> number of error message = number of textbox left. **I want just one
> error message for any number of text boxes** left while entering
> homephone number."*
>
> *"There is a `group_from` attribute but I am not able to implement it."*

There is no such thing as a `group_from` option.  However, the `groups` option will do what you want.  It simply combines all error messages for multiple fields into one.

```
$("#signup").validate({
    rules: {
        "data[User][homephone1]": {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            rangelength: [3, 3]
        },
        "data[User][homephone2]": {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            rangelength: [3, 3]
        },
        "data[User][homephone3]": {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            rangelength: [4, 4]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "data[User][homephone1]": "Please enter a valid Phone Number",
        "data[User][homephone2]": "Please enter a valid Phone Number",
        "data[User][homephone3]": "Please enter a valid Phone Number"
    },
    groups: {
        phoneGroup: "data[User][homephone1] data[User][homephone2] data[User][homephone3]"
    }
});
```

- The group name, `phoneGroup` is totally arbitrary and not used anyplace else.
- You also have the option to specify one message *per field* under the `messages` option.
- The `minlength` and `maxlength` rules can be combined into the `rangelength` rule.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/JdTZd/**