# jQuery Validation - Is there anyway to attach a rule to the form and not just for its elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form and each of its elements have their own custom rules working just fine, but I have a situation that the form can't be submmited without providing values for at least one of its elements.

I think this is a rule for the whole form and not for one specific element. I wrote a method that receives all the IDs of the form elements and checkes if they have values and attach it to a element of the form that is not passed as argument to this method, but I didn't think this is the best way to do it.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: As requested here's the method:**

```
$.validator.addMethod("atLeastOne", function(value, element, params) {
    if (!value) return false;
    $.each(params, function(i, param) {
        if (!$(param).val()) return false;
    }
};
```

And in my form:

```
$("form").validate(
    rules: {
        field1: { atLeastOne: ["#field2","#field3","#field4","#field5","#field6"] }
});
```

Comment: we need to see some code to help you

Comment: @GertB. code provided!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate, out of two blank fields, at least one field must be filled or both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136943/jquery-validate-out-of-two-blank-fields-at-least-one-field-must-be-filled-or-b)

Comment: Yes, that question is solving the same problem. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as attaching a rule to the `form` element using this plugin, that is impossible.

As far as making one field required out of a group of fields, use the `require_from_group` method contained in [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).

```
$("form").validate(
    rules: {
        field1: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.myGroupClass']
        },
        field2: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.myGroupClass']
        },
        field3: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.myGroupClass']
        }
    }
});
```

The first parameter is how many fields from the group are required.  The second parameter does not have to be a `class`, but it needs to be a valid jQuery selector that targets *only* the fields in your group.

**NOTE**:  You **must** use version 1.11.1 of both the plugin and the `additional-methods.js` file where the `require_from_group` bug was finally fixed.

Comment: Actually, this did not work, I'll try to use the bugfix listed in https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412. Are there any chances that this is not working because my fields already have other rules attached to them?

Comment: @Philippe, You **must** use version 1.11.1 of both the plugin and the `additional-methods.js` file where the bug was finally fixed.

Comment: Now it is working! The problem with yor answer is that you wrote "required_from_group", but the correct name of the method is "require_from_group", with no "d". Thanks again for your time and help!

Comment: @Philippe, sorry about that.  That's what happens when I rush.  Fixed.

Comment: No problem at all. Let me ask you one more question: you suggested //  for your custom message
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        require_from_group: jQuery.format("'Please enter either username/ email address to recover password'/Please fill out at least {0} of these fields.")
    }); in your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136943/jquery-validate-out-of-two-blank-fields-at-least-one-field-must-be-filled-or-b, isn't this making this answer as default for all the pages that uses this method?

Comment: @Philippe, it's JavaScript so it can only affect the page it's loaded on.

Comment: True, forgot about that. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi, `require_from_group` has nothing do with `skip_or_fill_minimum`.  The `require_from_group` bug was already fixed in 1.11.1, unless you have new information that nobody else knows about.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi, any bug complaints on SO about `require_from_group` always clear up when the version is updated to 1.11.1.  I am going to defer to the developer and the many months he spent working with all the people on SO and GitHub fixing `require_from_group` for version 1.11.1.

Comment: I read people confirming that in *1.11.1* the bug is fixed, I myself was one of them, but since the `skip_or_fill_minimun` bug still exists and it was very much the same of `require_from_group` and they both were corrected in the same commit I think that may still be a problem.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi, maybe.  Although we're not seeing any SO complaints about it either.  Not yet at least.

Comment: I'll wait for your contact with the developer. Let me know about it, please.