# Class based validations showing wrong output?

Tags: jquery, validation

Here I'm trying to do jQuery class based validation and it works well but it shows wrong output as well. when I click on search button in search field below fields are getting validated. I'm not getting why is it so happening?

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: could you reformule your questions making it more undertable? what do you wanna achive and whats the problem. Show us a bit of code...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using JQuery Validated Plugin. So read the documentation to know how specify the number of fields required.

Look this question, maybe could help you: [Jquery Validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136943/jquery-validate-out-of-two-blank-fields-at-least-one-field-must-be-filled-or-b)

Comment: it works fine on local machine but when we convert our page into aspx it will show wrong.
I have shown image in above link.when i click on search button, why below fields getting validated?