# Jquery Validation Any one of the fields mandatory

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using the [Jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), I was curious to know if there is some sort of in-built functionality to have a "one of the two" is mandatory check. e.g: Email or mobile number is mandatory?

Comment: Ok this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300994/jquery-validate-require-at-least-one-field-in-a-group-to-be-filled Can an op please close/take appropriate action for this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok serves me right for not googling enough.

To answer the question, by default No apparently it's not, but it isn't too difficult to write a custom rule either.

Rebecca has posted a solution on her blog at http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2009/04/15/jquery-validation-indicate-that-at-least-one-element-in-a-group-is-required/