# How to extending Jquery validatation to validate 2 of 3 required phone number?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation and here is the extension that I am using to validate US phone number.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
            phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
    }, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

This works great, but what if I only want to validate 2 of the 3 numbers.

For an example, I have

```
Home Phone: <input name="h" ...>
Work Phone: <input name="w" ...>
Cell Phone: <input name="c" ...>


$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    h: {phoneUS: true},
    w: {phoneUS: true},
    c: {phoneUS: true}
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here:

[jQuery Validate - require at least one field in a group to be filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300994/jquery-validate-require-at-least-one-field-in-a-group-to-be-filled)

Also, before I found this I did come up with my own solution that works.

```
h: {
    phoneUS: true,
    required: function(element) {
        return ($('input.phones:blank').length >= 2);
    }
},
c: {
    phoneUS: true,
    required: function(element) {
        return ($('input.phones:blank').length >= 2);
    }
},
w: {
    phoneUS: true,
    required: function(element) {
        return ($('input.phones:blank').length >= 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use class in input fields

```
Home Phone: <input name="h" class="phones">
Work Phone: <input name="w" class="phones">
Cell Phone: <input name="c" class="phones">
```

and change your jquery

```
$('.phones').validate({
  rules: {
    h: {phoneUS: true},
    w: {phoneUS: true},
    c: {phoneUS: true}
  }
});
```

Comment: how does this required at least 2 of the 3 phone numbers being entered? One of these condition has to be true: home+work or work+cell or home+cell combination.