# jQuery Validation : require either valid phone or valid email

Tags: jquery, validation

First day with jQuery Validation but not first day with jQuery.  Very simple question: I have three text inputs: name, phone, and email.  I want to require name (no sweat) and EITHER phone OR email, and make sure the input is valid in EITHER phone OR email.  I've tried this with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#contactForm").validate({
    debug:true,
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            email:true,
            required: function(element){
                !$("#phone").valid();   
            }
        },
        phone: {
            phoneUS: true,
            required: function(element){
                !$("#email").valid();   
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please specify your name",
        email: {
            required: "Please enter a valid email"
        },
        phone: "Please enter a 10 digit phone number"
    }
});
```

});

But it fails because each validity check calls the other, recursing infinitely and crashing the browser.

There has to be some easy way to do this, but I've spent close to two hours on it and it escapes me :(

Comment: Psst. [jQuery Validate: Require at least one field in a group to be filled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300994/jquery-validate-require-at-least-one-field-in-a-group-to-be-filled)

Comment: But it seems like such a hack.  I guess I assumed (wrongly) that jQuery Validation would be able to handle this sort of thing elegantly :(

Comment: Creating a custom validator isn't "elegant" in your eyes?

Comment: When all you need is something this simple, yes, writing a custom validator that depends on appending classes to inputs to avoid infinite recursion is inelegant.  I had hoped jQuery Validation would be able to handle conditional logic like this natively.  Other than that, it is a very good validation library.

Comment: Yes!  It looks like the jQuery team has now addressed this situation - https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/78a739f7c574c80547dfecd70b46a362efc8e8a7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, super simple solution, forgot to post it earlier - intercept the form submission, manually validate first, then trigger plugin validation.  Here's an example that requires one of n checkboxes to be selected (adapted from an actual project, so it might have some typos, but you get the jist):

```
(document).ready(function() {
       // on form submission
       $('form#signup').submit(function() {
                // make sure a checkbox is selected
                var checked = false;
                $('input.checkboxGroupMember').each(function(index) {
                    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                        checked = true;
                    }
                });
                if (checked == false) {
                    // do whatever to handle the failure here
                    $('div#feedback').html('Please select a checkbox');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('form#signup').validate();
                }

            });

            // once a checkbox is selected, clear feedback
            $('form input.checkboxGroupMember').change(function(index) {
                if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                    $('div#feedback').empty();
                }
            });

            $('form#signup').validate();
        });
```

Can be adapted easily to deal with whatever validation is required that you don't want to do via jQuery validation plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own method by

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "email_or_phone_number", 
    (value, element) => {
        this.optional(element) || /*is optional*/
        /^\d{10,11}$/.test(value) || /*is phone number*/
        /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(value) /*is email*/
    },
    "Please enter either phone number or e-mail"
);
```

Now you can use method "email_or_phone_number"
For multidata case:

```
<input type="text" class="{email_or_phone_number:true}" value="" />
```

You can change regular expression within method by your own needs

Comment: Is this working in 2020? I am getting the error in console TypeError: this.optional is not a function.  Exception occurred when checking element emailphone, check the 'email_or_phone_number' method.

Answer (score 2):

**Define Custom Method**
Here mobile no considers as Indian mobile no length (10 digits).You can change accordingly. [Email Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

```
$.validator.addMethod("email_or_mobile", function(value, element) {
        return /^\d{10,10}$/.test(value) ||   //Indian Mobile No. Lenth 10 
            /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(value) //email
}, "Please enter valid email or mobile");
```

**Form Validation**

```
 $('#loginForm').validate({
        rules: {

            email: {
                required: true,
                email_or_mobile: true //check custom method
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email/mobile"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please enter your password",
            }
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, a better solution now available is jQuery Groups. [Example of jQuery Groups](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/). Validation will look like the following

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    mobile_phone: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
    },
    home_phone: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
    },
    work_phone: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".phone-group"]
    }
  }
});
```

Your three fields each will have the class="phone-group".

Make sure to include **additional-methods.min.js** which is required for groups validation.