# How to validate a field such that user can give either email or phoneno.?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin on my form.It has an 'Username' field . User can give either email or phoneno as username . How can I validate this field ? I tried this code :

```
<form id="login">
<input id="username" name="username" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<script>

$("#login").validate(

    {
  rules: {
   username: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
    email:true
              }
           }
         });
```

Comment: Write regular expressions for the two types of input, and combine them with `|`: `/emailregexp|phonenoregexp/`

Comment: _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)._"

Comment: do you mean writing two input tags and comibining jquery for their ids with "|"            my preent code is                                <!--html-->                                                     <form id="login">
<input id="username" name="username" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>                                                              <script>                                                                   $("#login").validate(
 {
  rules: {
   
 username: {
      required: true,
      number: true,
  email:true
    }
 
 
  }
}
);


</script>

Comment: Your question is three short sentences.  At least put forth as much effort into writing your question as somebody else would have to put forth answering it for you.

Comment: @Barmar means that you'll have to write a custom rule using regex.  See [the `addMethod` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) of the plugin.  Also look at [the source code of the plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js) to see how regex is used within the methods.

Comment: @Sparky is right. jquery-validate doesn't have any built-in multi-type validation, so you have to write your own method.

Comment: Do not put chunks of code into comments!  Just edit your question to make it better.

Comment: Thanks Barmar and  Sparky for help, my problem is fixed by using addmethod

Comment: Please post your detailed answer below for the benefit of others.

Comment: I used the addmethod given in the question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393662/jquery-validation-require-either-valid-phone-or-valid-email), (same as stated by @Barmar)  added this method to additional-methods.js file of plugin and used this in input as given example in link, it works well.