# multiple field validation with jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two input checkboxes as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="items[test1]" id="items_test1">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="items[test2]" id="items_test2">
```

I want atleast one of them to be checked.
For that I added jquery validate plugin code as below:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("checkTest", function(value) {
    return false; // return false just to check whether it triggers error
}, 'Please check atleast one');

 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("form").validate({
         groups: {
            checkTest: 'items[test1] items[test2]'
         },
         errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
              console.log(error);
     });
 });
```

This check is nevered triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up the group, but you haven't added any validation rules to your checkboxes.  I would use the require_from_group method found in the additional methods file of the plugin.  In document ready:

```
// add a class to the checkboxes in the group, here I have added to all
$('[type=checkbox]').addClass('test_checkboxes');

// set up a rule for the class
$.validator.addClassRules("test_checkboxes", {
    require_from_group: [1, ".test_checkboxes"]
});

$("form").validate({
    groups: {
        checkTest: 'items[test1] items[test2]'
    }
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k75Za/1/)

Comment: I know sometimes documentation for this plugin is sparse, but is there anything written for `require_from_group` you could link to?

Comment: for documentation on require_from_group there is an original post on this method on SO here http://stackoverflow.com/q/1300994/678338

Comment: sonam this is a new question eg 'how to specify a custom error messages when using validate plugin groups option'

Comment: @sonam, [see this jsFiddle for how to use a the custom error message for `require_from_group` option:  jsfiddle.net/LWwxL/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/LWwxL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to do this using validate plugin, but just in case if you want to go manually then you can use this method.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="items[test1]" id="items_test1">
    <br>
    Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="items[test2]" id="items_test2">

    <br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
        if($('#items_test1').is(':checked') || $('#items_test2').is(':checked')) {
             alert('done. valid form submission.');   
        } else {
             alert('invalid form submission, check atleast one checkbox.');   
        }
        return false; 
    });
})
```

You can find this on [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5CBqH/1/).

Comment: sorry i am not looking for solution other than jquery validate plugin