# Unable to get form to validate for one or other input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to get it so if user fills out at least one of inputs then form gets submitted.

I guess I'm not sure what this code: [jQuery Validate - require at least one field in a group to be filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300994/jquery-validate-require-at-least-one-field-in-a-group-to-be-filled) is doing well enough to get it to work for me.

Any help would be appreciated:

After i looked at the answer above I tried this:

I have this form:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input class="fillone" id="bigform" name="message" type="text" required/>
  <input class="fillone" id="bigform" name="number" type="text" required/>
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

and script:

```
if(!$(element).data('being_validated')) {
     var fields = $(selector, element.form);
     fields.data('being_validated', true);
     fields.valid();
     fields.data('being_validated', false);
   }
  return validOrNot;
  }, jQuery.format("Please fill at least {0} of these fields."));

  $.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
    var selector = options[1];
    var validOrNot = $(selector, element.form).filter(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).length >= options[0];

  $("#myForm").validate({
    groups: {
      message:  {require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]},
      number: {require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]},
  });
```

Comment: You're missing a quote `$("#myForm)`

Comment: Also, I think `jQuery.validator.addMethod` should be at the top, since you're using in `$("#myForm")`.  For example `alert(testVar); var testVar = 'this is after it is alerting.';` Although it still works, it's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Thx, I wish it was a fix but at least its syntactically correct now.

Comment: I have it in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/P4WBx/

Comment: Actually, my bad, the script should be arranged like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9ApsV/
This still doesn't fix it, but I thought I'd point that out, again.

Comment: thx I edited above with your correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire script is jumbled nonsense and filled with syntax errors.... a compilation of disconnected bits and pieces.  It's exactly like you cut `require_from_group` into two chunks of code and swapped those two pieces after deleting some things...

```
if(!$(element).data('being_validated')) {  // this part comes from INSIDE 'require_from_group'
     var fields = $(selector, element.form);
     fields.data('being_validated', true);
     fields.valid();
     fields.data('being_validated', false);
   }
  return validOrNot;
  // this line should be the last line of 'addMethod', NOT after a comma following a conditional
  }, jQuery.format("Please fill at least {0} of these fields."));  

  // this is start of 'addMethod" but its guts are just above    
  $.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
    var selector = options[1];
    var validOrNot = $(selector, element.form).filter(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).length >= options[0];  // 'addMethod' can't end here!

  $("#myForm").validate({
    // this is all wrong...
    groups: {
      message:  {require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]},
      number: {require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]},
  });
```

Forget about manually including `required_from_group`.  Just include [the *latest* `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) which already has a working `required_from_group` method inside.

Now let's talk about your implementation of the `.validate()` method...

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    groups: {
          message:  {require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]},
          number: {require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]},
});
```

and your HTML:

```
<input class="fillone" id="bigform" name="message" type="text" required/>
<input class="fillone" id="bigform" name="number" type="text" required/>
```

**Problems**:

1)  The `groups` option is only used for grouping error messages together, **not for assigning rules**.  It only contains an arbitrary name and a space separated list of field names whose messages are to be grouped together.  Don't confuse this *option* with the `require_from_group` rule.  Although they can be used together, they are not related to each other.  [See documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

```
groups: {  // group some messages together
    myGroup:  "message number"  // names of fields to group their messages
} // <- you were also missing this closing brace
```

2)  *Whenever* rules are declared within the `.validate()` method, they **must be declared by using the `rules` option**.  I don't see the `rules` option within your `.validate()`.

```
rules: {  // declare the rules
    message: {  // name of field
        require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]
    },
    number: {  // name of field
        require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]
    }
}
```

3)  You've placed the `required` attribute inside both of your `input` elements.  This tells the plugin that **both** fields have the `required` rule.  If you only want one or the other `required`, then you also can't make them both `required`.  `require_from_group[1, ..]` means that *at least one from the group* is `required`.  Remove the `required` attribute from the `input` elements if you really want to use the `require_from_group` rule.

```
<input class="fillone" id="bigform" name="message" type="text" />
<input class="fillone" id="bigform" name="number" type="text" />
```

---

```
$("#myForm").validate({  // initialize the plugin
    rules: {  // declare the rules
        message: {  // name of field
            require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]
        },
        number: {  // name of field
            require_from_group: [1,".fillone"]
        }
    },
    groups: {  // group some messages together
        myGroup:  "message number"  // names of fields to group their messages
    }
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/DB5ZL/**